# Error importing numpy & graphlab after installing ipython

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, graphlab

I have got a strange issue.

I am now using graphlab/numpy to develop a project via Pycharm 5. OS is Mac OS 10.11.5. I created a p2.7 virtual environment for the project. Programme runs well. But after I install ipython, I can no longer import graphlab and numpy correctly.

Error message:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'

System keeps telling that attribute ‘core' and 'connect' are missing. But I am pretty sure that they can be found in graphlab/numpy folders, and no duplicates.

Project runs all right in terminal. Now I have to uninstall ipython. Then everything is ok again.

Please kindly help.

Comment: I am getting that error as well. I thought it had something to do with upgrading to graphlab-create v1.10. I sometimes get your error in iPython. Usually I get `ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ion/anaconda/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/cython/cy_unity.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Users/ion/anaconda/envs/dato-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/cython/cy_unity.so: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00`

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that console applications and GUI application do not share the same environment on OS X.

This also means that if you install a Python package from the console, this would probably not be visible to PyCharm.

Usually you need to install packages using PyCharm in order to be able to use them.

Answer (score 0):

[Upgrading pip itself then reinstalling worked for me](http://forum.dato.com/discussion/comment/3986/#Comment_3986)